# SystemVerilog - Accessing Elements in an Array with $realtobits()

Tags: system-verilog

When I try to access a value from an array in SystemVerilog with the `$realtobits()` function, I am getting some anger from ModelSim:

```
reg [1:0] TEST_VALUE;
localparam real TEST_TABLE [0:3] = { 8, 9, 10, 11 };
initial begin
   TEST_VALUE = $realtobits( TEST_TABLE[2] );
   $display( "0x%X", TEST_VALUE );
end
```

I can compile it, but when I try to load the design for simulation in ModelSim I get:

```
# vsim -voptargs=+acc work.top 
# Loading sv_std.std
# Loading work.top
# ** Error: (vsim-PLI-3077) /home/russv/sdi2x_hdmi/firmware/shared/video/video_signal_format_table.sv(64): $realtobits : Function takes only one argument of type real.
#         Region: /top
# Error loading design
```

(Operative text: `$realtobits : Function takes only one argument of type real.`)

It seems to me that by indexing into the array of `real` values, I should be accessing a single value of type real.  And there's only one argument - there's no comma in the function call.

Thoughts?  In the end I actually want to access into a 2-dimensional array, but I feel like if I can crack this test case I can figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting that error message when I try your code. You should not be using $realtobits anyways. That was a hack for passing real numbers through Verilog ports in Verilog, where ports had be be integral values.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using an explicit array cast to do the conversion:

```
typedef reg [N:0] reg_N_bits_wide_t;
...
SYNTHESIZED_TABLE[i] = reg_N_bits_wide_t'(REAL_VALUE_TABLE[i]);
```

In case anyone else ends up here.

Comment: You should not need any cast or conversion function; this is handled implicitly.